# Is there a way to see HDD temp.?? I am using lubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lm-sensors

I am currently using lm-sensors, but it shows only the CPU temp.
I need to see the HDD temp. as well

Is there any way to do it??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install hddtemp
```

That will install hddtemp. To find HDD temperature, use the syntax:

```
sudo hddtemp /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 6):

Install the smartmontools package:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

Then (assuming the disk you want to check is sda) run

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

and the temperature will be in the output (mine is item number 194)