# Tool to Monitor HDD Temperature in Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: server, hard-drive, 22.04, temperature

Is there a tool to monitor HDD Temperature in Ubuntu Server 22.04? I know tools exists such as `hddtemp`, `smartmontools`, `lsm-sensors`, and `inxi` but none displayed my HDD Temperature.

**hddtemp**

Installing it with `sudo apt-get install hddtemp`shows that its not available in my Ubuntu version.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package hddtemp is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'hddtemp' has no installation candidate
```

**smartmontools, lsm-sensors, and inxi**

This package is available in my version but doesn't output my hdd temps. My assumption is that certain sensors need to be configured to get the hddtemp.

What I did was:

1. Install `inxi`: `sudo apt-get install inxi`
2. Configure `lsm-sensors`: `sudo sensors-detect`
3. Run `sudo inxi -xD`

Output:

```
Local Storage: total: 11.83 TiB used: 17.17 GiB (0.1%)
ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM035-1RK172 size: 931.51 GiB
ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD6NPURX-64JC5Y0 size: 5.46 TiB
ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Western Digital model: WD6NPURX-64JC5Y0 size: 5.46 TiB
```

Even running `smartmontools` as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/584113/1566979) doesn't provide hdd temps.

I also researched here but to no avail.

Example

1. [CPU and HDDs temperature in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419590/cpu-and-hdds-temperature-in-ubuntu-22-04)
2. [How to check USB HDD temperature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674923/how-to-check-usb-hdd-temperature)
3. [How to check USB HDD temperature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674923/how-to-check-usb-hdd-temperature)

Comment: did you check via `sudo smartctl -A /dev/sd(your drive letter) | grep -i temperature
`

Comment: It does indeed solve my problem.

`194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   113   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       39`

As far as I know, the temp is the last value: `39`. Am I correct?

Write it as an answer and I will mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for GUI

```
sudo apt install gsmartcontrol
```

or in terminal

```
sudo smartctl -A /dev/sd(your drive letter) | grep -i temperature
```

This will show you either print correct temperature for your SDD/HDD

Answer (score 3):

To read HDD temperatures in Ubuntu 22.04 you need to use `hwmon`, which can be accessed using `sensors` when the `drivetemp` module is loaded.

```
sudo apt install lm-sensors
sudo modprobe drivetemp
sensors
```

To make `drivetemp` load automatically every boot, add it to /etc/modules as follows:

```
echo drivetemp | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Comment: no temps for HDD. Only the cpu temps are showing which is not the desired.

[Output Here](https://pastebin.com/YDdkgQqc)

Comment: They are there, look for the drivetemp-scsi-1-0 entries

Comment: How can I correlate the `sensors` output to specific disks, e.g. to determine the temperature of `/dev/sda`?

Comment: @MartinvonWittich please see my latest answer below for an alternative that allows `/dev` name matching

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my previous answer, I have found that the single most reliable source of temperature data is still smartctl. This allows matching on `/dev` names but it is much messier and requires a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DRIVEPATH="$1"
INFO="$(sudo smartctl -a $DRIVEPATH)"
TEMP=$(echo "$INFO" | grep '194 Temp' | awk '{print $10}')
if [[ $TEMP == '' ]]; then
  TEMP=$(echo "$INFO" | grep '190 Airflow' | awk '{print $10}')
fi
if [[ $TEMP == '' ]]; then
  TEMP=$(echo "$INFO" | grep 'Temperature Sensor 1:' | awk '{print $4}')
fi
if [[ $TEMP == '' ]]; then
  TEMP=$(echo "$INFO" | grep 'Current Drive Temperature:' | awk '{print $4}')
fi
if [[ $TEMP == '' ]]; then
  TEMP=$(echo "$INFO" | grep 'Temperature:' | awk '{print $2}')
fi
echo $TEMP
```

Example:

```
$ sudo gethddtemp /dev/sda
34
```

Perhaps it could be improved into a `for` loop with each `grep | awk` statement.

The above works across all our SATA HDD, SATA SSD, SAS HDD and NVMe drives but more cases may be needed to support other vendors, models and interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the hard disk temperatures listed in `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zoneX/temp`. Replace X with the number if more than one hard disk.

For individual names of hard disks if you have more than one you can look at
`/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zoneX/type`

To check all of the hard disks and their temperature without third party tools.

```
paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t | sed 's/\(.\)..$/.\1°C/'
```

Source [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-cpu-temp#ftoc-heading-5)

Comment: Running your command outputs only the cpu temp as shown below  

Command:  
`paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t | sed 's/\(.\)..$/.\1°C/'`  

Output:  
`x86_pkg_temp  40.0°C`

What I need is to output the temps for HDD.

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function to check if a drive exists and retrieve its temperature
get_drive_temperature() {
  local drive="$1"
  local info="$(sudo smartctl -a $drive)"
  local temp=$(echo "$info" | grep '194 Temp' | awk '{print $10}')
  if [[ $temp == '' ]]; then
    temp=$(echo "$info" | grep '190 Airflow' | awk '{print $10}')
  fi
  if [[ $temp == '' ]]; then
    temp=$(echo "$info" | grep 'Temperature Sensor 1:' | awk '{print $4}')
  fi
  if [[ $temp == '' ]]; then
    temp=$(echo "$info" | grep 'Current Drive Temperature:' | awk '{print $4}')
  fi
  if [[ $temp == '' ]]; then
    temp=$(echo "$info" | grep 'Temperature:' | awk '{print $2}')
  fi
  echo "$temp"
}

# Function to retrieve the core temperature
get_core_temperature() {
  local core_temp=$(sensors | grep 'Core 0:' | awk '{print $3}')
  echo "$core_temp"
}

# Get and print core temperature first
core_temperature=$(get_core_temperature)
echo "Core temperature: $core_temperature"

# Print drive temperatures
for drive in /dev/sd?; do
  if [ -e "$drive" ]; then
    temperature=$(get_drive_temperature "$drive")
    echo "$drive temperature: $temperature DegC"
  fi
done
```